# Drawing text boxes on a map shows boxes all at once instead of single box

Tags: java, 2d, rendering, mouseevent

Basically I have a map with cities on it, each city has their own longtitue and latitude. I have excell file which contains population of each city that need to be displayed in a textbox when a box is clicked.
I am having an issue with the data being shown all at once and only one of the boxes on the map is clickable even though I have the code for more than once city.

```
PImage img;
// variables for moving image around
int updown = 0;
int leftright = 0;
int radius = 10, direction, directionX=1, directionY=0;

PVector pos2D = new PVector();

// variables for using the mouse to navigate around the sphere
float rotx = PI/4;
float roty = PI/4;
float xcoord, ycoord;
float rotateX, rotateY, camX, camY, camZ;
float x=20, y=20;
float speed=0.5;

String[][] data;

// variables to enable zooming with mouse wheel
float wheelCount = 0;
float mwX = 0;
float mwY = 0;
float zoom = 1;

int screen = 0; // variable for different screens

boolean drawText = false;

void setup() {
  size(800, 600, P3D);
  img = loadImage("uk-admin.jpg");
  textSize(12);
  smooth();
  noStroke();
  String[] lines = loadStrings("Data.csv"); // reads contents of files
  println("There are " + lines.length + " lines");   
  String[] header = split(lines[0], ','); // seperates data
  println(String.join("   ", header)); // joins all headers
  data = new String[lines.length-1][header.length-1]; // checks the columns and rows
  for (int i = 1 ; i < lines.length; i++) {
        String[] dataStr = split(lines[i], ',');
        data[i-1] = dataStr;
        println(String.join("  ", dataStr));
    }
}

void draw() {
background(0);
noStroke();

beginCamera();
camera(width/2.0, height/2.0, (height/2.0) / tan(PI*30.0 / 180.0), width/2.0, height/2.0, 0, 0, 1, 0);
translate(leftright,updown);
endCamera();

//changes position
  x=x+speed*directionX;
  y=y+speed*directionY;
  
  //checks boundaries
  if ((x>width-radius) || x<radius)
  {
    directionX=-directionX;
  }
  if ((y>height-radius) || (y<radius))
  {
    directionY=-directionY;
  }
  
  if(direction==1)
  rect(x, y, 20, 20);
  
  imageMode(CENTER);
  
  translate(camX, camY, camZ);
  translate(width/2.0-camX, height/2.0-camY);
  rotateY(rotateY);
  rotateX(rotateX);
  translate(-(width/2.0-camX), -(height/2.0-camY));


// sets zooming level for mousewheel
if (wheelCount != 0) {
    mwX=mouseX;
    mwY=mouseY;
    zoom-=wheelCount/50;
    wheelCount = 0; 
}
translate(mwX, mwY);
scale(zoom);
translate(-(mwX), -(mwY));
translate(width / 2, height / 2, 340);

// 1991 map
if(screen == 0) {
    fill(255);
    textSize(12); 
    text("1891", 100, -80, 0);

beginShape();
texture(img);
vertex(-100, -100, 0, 0, 0);
vertex(100, -100, 0, img.width, 0);
vertex(100, 100, 0, img.width, img.height);
vertex(-100, 100, 0, 0, img.height);
endShape();

//frankfurt
pushMatrix();
fill(0); 
translate(55, 75);
box (2, 2, 2);
pos2D.set(screenX(0, 0), screenY(0, 0));
popMatrix(); 

if ( dist(mouseX, mouseY, pos2D.x, pos2D.y)<60 ) {
    cursor(HAND);
 }else {
    cursor(ARROW);
 }
    if (drawText) {
      fill(#000000);
      textSize(12);
      text("6.715.769", 55, 75);
    }
  
//berlin
pushMatrix();
fill(0);
translate(32, 51);
box (2, 2, 2);
pos2D.set(screenX(0, 0, 0), screenY(0, 0, 0));
popMatrix(); 

if ( dist(mouseX, mouseY, pos2D.x, pos2D.y)<60 ) {
    cursor(HAND);
 }else {
    cursor(ARROW);
 }
    if (drawText) {
      fill(#000000);
      textSize(12);
      text("965.928", 27, 59);
    }

// dortmund
pushMatrix();
fill(0);
textSize(12); 
translate(12, -29);
box (2, 2, 2);
pos2D.set(screenX(0, 0, 0), screenY(0, 0, 0));
popMatrix();

if ( dist(mouseX, mouseY, pos2D.x, pos2D.y)<60 ) {
    cursor(HAND);
 }else {
    cursor(ARROW);
 }
    if (drawText) {
      fill(#000000);
      textSize(12);
      text("NO DATA", 12, -29);
      textSize(12);
    }

}
// 1901 map
if(screen == 1) {
    //shows 2001 data
     fill(248, 255, 6);
    text("2001", 100, -80, 0);

beginShape();
texture(img);
vertex(-100, -100, 0, 0, 0);
vertex(100, -100, 0, img.width, 0);
vertex(100, 100, 0, img.width, img.height);
vertex(-100, 100, 0, 0, img.height);
endShape();

//reading
pushMatrix();
fill(204, 0, 0, 151);
translate(42, 75, 0);
box (5, 5, 10);
popMatrix();

//Manchester
pushMatrix();
fill(204, 0, 0, 151);
translate(34, 86, 0);
box (5, 5, 10);
popMatrix();

// London
pushMatrix();
fill(204, 0, 0, 151);
translate(28, 65, 0);
box (5, 5, 10);
popMatrix();

}

//2001 map
if(screen == 2) {
    //shows 2011 data
    fill(248, 255, 6);
    text("2011", 100, -80, 0);
    
beginShape();
texture(img);
vertex(-100, -100, 0, 0, 0);
vertex(100, -100, 0, img.width, 0);
vertex(100, 100, 0, img.width, img.height);
vertex(-100, 100, 0, 0, img.height);
endShape();

// Las Vegas
pushMatrix();
fill(204, 0, 0, 151);
translate(55, 75, 0);
box (5, 5, 10);
popMatrix();

//LA
pushMatrix();
fill(204, 0, 0, 151);
translate(32, 51, 0);
box (5, 5, 10);
popMatrix();

//new york
pushMatrix();
fill(204, 0, 0, 151);
translate(30, 29, 0);
box (5, 5, 10);
popMatrix();
}

}


void keyPressed() {
  if (key == CODED) {
    if (keyCode == UP) { // moves camera up
      updown = updown+30;
    } else if (keyCode == DOWN) { // moves camera down
      updown = updown-30;
    } else if (keyCode == RIGHT) { // moves camera right
      leftright = leftright-30;
    } else if (keyCode == LEFT) { // moves camera left
      leftright = leftright+30;
    }
    
  }
}

void mouseWheel(MouseEvent event) {
  wheelCount = event.getCount();
}

  //allows button click to switch between scenes.
void mousePressed(MouseEvent event) {
  if (mouseButton == RIGHT) {
    screen = (screen + 1) % 3;
    }
    if (event.getCount() == 1) {  // detect double click
    if (mouseButton == LEFT && dist(mouseX,mouseY, pos2D.x, pos2D.y)<60) {
    drawText = ! drawText;
  }
}
}
void mouseDragged() {
  if (mouseButton == RIGHT) {
    rotateY += (pmouseX - mouseX)*0.01;
    rotateX += (pmouseY - mouseY)*0.01;
  } if (mouseButton == LEFT) {
    camX -= (pmouseX - mouseX);
    camY -= (pmouseY - mouseY);
  } 
}
```

For some reason only box for Berlin is clickable, the rest isn't. When I click Berlin on the map it shows the data for all the cities that have the above piece of code added.
I need to be able to filter within the cities for example I click Berlin so only data for Berlin pops up.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What's in your `mouseClicked` method?

Comment: I do assume that you have some kind of "City" class which makes `pos2D` unique for each city?

Comment: ```void mousePressed(MouseEvent event) {
  if (mouseButton == RIGHT) {
    screen = (screen + 1) % 3;
    }
    if (event.getCount() == 1) {  // detect double click
    if (mouseButton == LEFT && dist(mouseX,mouseY, pos2D.x, pos2D.y)<60) {
    drawText = ! drawText;
  }
```
@laancelot just the latitude and longtitute represents where the city on the map is

Comment: Which city does `pos2D` refers to? All of them?

Comment: It seems like it refers to all of the cities because when I left click on the box, data of all cities appear at the same time making it very messy on the map. I want to make it 1 box click - data of the specific city appear but I am having troubles doing that.

Comment: I don't how long your code is, but I suggest that you post it all. The best would be a [Minimal, Reproductible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), but I'm willing to sift through your code anyway. (to post your code, please edit this question and add/modify what needs to be changed)

Answer (score 2):

The reason all text boxes pop up when you click is because you only one one single `drawText` variable that determines for every city whether to show the text or not. In a very simplified manner, what you have is this:

```
boolean drawText = false;

void draw() {

    // code for city 1...
    if (drawText) {
        // show text box for city 1
    }
    
    // code for city 2...
    if (drawText) {
        // show text box for city 2
    }
    
    // and so on
    
}

void mousePressed(MouseEvent event) {
    
    // if left click...
    drawText = !drawText;
    
}
```

Either `drawText` is true or false, and if it is true then for every city the text will be shown. You don't have a separate boolean per city.

Then the reason why only one of your boxes seems to work, and probably also the reason you incorrectly misunderstood which one would be shown, is this part:

```
if (mouseButton == LEFT && dist(mouseX,mouseY, pos2D.x, pos2D.y)<60) {
    drawText = ! drawText;
}
```

That `if` there tests if the distance of the mouse to the `pos2D` coordinates is lower than 60. But since you update the `pos2D` with every city and all the cities are just created in one big code block, this only checks for the distance to the last city to be added where the `pos2D` is updated (Dortmund). Simplified, what you are doing is comparable to this:

```
int test = 0;
int input = 10;

void draw() {
    
    // first
    test = 1;
    if (input == test)
        // do something
    
    // second
    test = 2;
    if (input == test)
        // do something
    
    // and so on until...
    
    // tenth
    test = 10;
    if (input == test)
        //do something

}

void mouseClicked(MouseEvent event) {
    
    // set input based on something from mouse...
    input = getMouseInput(event);
    
    if (input == test)
        drawText = !drawText;
    
}
```

The above is just for illustration. Carefully check it and think of what would happen if you call `draw()` and then `mouseClicked()`. What value will `test` have? If `test` represents some city, for which one would the `drawText` variable ever be changed? Can it ever work for other values?

The main problem with your code is that you use global variables like `drawText` and `pos2D` which are then changed throughout different methods. You have multiple cities but every city depends on one variable for whether its text box is drawn and every city depends on one variable for the position.

Java is an object-oriented language. For problems such as these such a language uses classes to model data and behaviour and then creates objects as instances of such classes. In your case it would help if you had a "City" class which has its own data and can respond to mouse clicks. Here's a quick draft that can get you started:

```
public class City {

    private final int xCoordinate;
    private final int yCoordinate;
    private final String text;
    private boolean drawText;
    
    public City(int xCoord, int yCoord, String boxText) {
        this.xCoordinate = xCoord;
        this.yCoordinate = yCoord;
        this.text = boxText;
        drawText = false;
    }
    
    public void draw() {
        pushMatrix();
        fill(0);
        translate(xCoordinate, yCoordinate);
        
        // and further methods needed for rendering
        // ...
        
        if (drawText) {
            fill(#000000);
            textSize(12);
            text(text, xCoordinate, yCoordinate);
        }
    }
    
    public boolean isMouseOnCity(int mouseX, int mouseY) {
        return dist(mouseX, mouseY, xCoordinate, yCoordinate) < 60;
    }   
    
}
```

You would then create a City object like `City dortmund = new City(12, -29, "NO DATA");`. Methods can be invoked on a city to perform logic, make changes to the data or get some result. For example, `dortmund.isMouseOnCity(mouseX, mouseY)` could check whether for the given mouse coordinates the cursor is located over dortmund or not. Method `dortmund.draw()` will only take care of drawing the data for that city based on its own variable values. The key is that the city coordinates, the text to display and whether to show the text or not are now **local** to a city instance.

Do some research on how to design proper object-oriented code in Java and then apply it to your code. I suspect you either come from a background of imperative programming (like C) or are rather new to programming entirely, so it can take a while to learn the best ways to do things in another paradigm.

Comment: I loved reading this. OOP is definitively the way to go here. Bonus points for adding how to check is the city is being hovered and adding the notion of scope.

Comment: @laancelot Thanks! I know this question may not be a perfect fit for SO where we favor clear questions with a concise answer, but I can't help but think that we have no idea of the asker's background. Having proper guidance could make the difference between someone giving up coding out of frustration or having a new future pro developer. I'll always consider SO a place to help fellow programmers first and foremost and am willing to take the effort to try and understand the question, no matter what the moderators may believe SO "should" really be.

Comment: Seems like we are like-minded. I too like to help when I can, but this is above and beyond duty. I like to think that new users will improve their "asking skills" if we nudge them in the right direction. This is definitively the right direction!